# SQL para pagina específica

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou fazendo meu próprio código de paginação de uma tabela de registros, e no meu caso não quero que somente a página requisitada venha por AJAX ao invés de todas as páginas para serem manipuladas pelo JavaScript.

A informação da quantidade de registros (*Necessária para calcular a quantidade de páginas*) sei que posso obter com `count()`, mas o `select` não sei como posso obter somente o da página que preciso, por exemplo, na situação em que a minha página vai ter apenas 10 registros sei que posso obter a primeira página limitando o resultado com `LIMIT 10` na minha *query*, mas e as outras páginas? Tenho como obter um determinado intervalo de resultados após a minha primeira página com SQL? Por exemplo quero somente 10 registros após os 10 primeiros. Tem esse recurso no SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No MySQL, você pode continuar usando o LIMIT para fazer isso. O LIMIT pode trabalhar com posiçâo inicial e quantidade de registros. Segue alguns exemplos:

```
SELECT * FROM minha_tabela ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 15
SELECT * FROM minha_tabela ORDER BY id LIMIT 15, 15
SELECT * FROM minha_tabela ORDER BY id LIMIT 30, 15
```

Neste exemplo, o 15 no final se refere a quantidade de registros a retornar, e o primeiro número e a posição do registro inicial